# Uiwebview size not setting as the content in webview

Tags: uiwebview, height

I have given a webview in Sectioned UiTableViewCell like this

```
if(section==0)
    {
      static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"Cell";
      UITableViewCell* cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
         if(cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]autorelease];


            webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
            webView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
            webView.tag = 1001;
            webView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
            webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            webView.opaque = NO;


            [cell addSubview:webView];
        }


     webView = (UIWebView*)[cell viewWithTag:1001];

        webView.delegate=self;
        webView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 1000);
        NSLog(@"current mode: %@", [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] currentMode]);
        [webView loadHTMLString: [NSString stringWithFormat:[arrSecCount objectAtIndex:0], indexPath.section]baseURL:nil];
         return cell;

    }

where as the content in webview is dynamic.in 

    - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

    {
    if(indexPath.section==0)
     {
        NSString *output = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.scrollHeight;"];

     return [output floatValue]+300;

      }
        }
```

but when content in webview increases it is overiding on other section not fitting height.i have been tried many methodson search but of no use.
Help me with your suggestions

Comment: what happened when you tried like this?

Comment: have you got the correct value in output object?

Comment: Yes but frame(height) is not setting properly.let me know If u notice anything wrong

Comment: means tableview height not changed right?

Comment: yes section height must be changed according with uiWebviw

Comment: section height or row height?

Comment: section height uiwebview must fill in that section that contains single number of rows

Answer (score 0):

I think the UITableViewCell will get its height before the content of the WebView is even loaded...

What is suggest is that in the delegate method of the webview :

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
```

you do a

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

That means you have to keep a reference to the webview and not reloading the HTMLString everytime the cell content is updated...

Comment: Yes you do, my answer assume the method heightForRowAtIndexPath is called before your webview finished loading. Which means, the webview won't have any content to display yet, and the height won't be correct.

Comment: - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    CGRect frame = self.webView.frame;
    frame.size = [self.webView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
frame.size.height += 20.0f; // additional padding to push it off the bottom edge
    self.webView.frame = frame;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
   
      [self performSelector:@selector(stopRunLoop) withObject:nil afterDelay:.01];
    
}

Comment: Depending on how you impletemented tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: it seems right...

Comment: then how to give dynamic height